# Fix for network filter deletions

Tags: script

### Description

#### Problem

See the report: [Can't delete the filter called My Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324759/cant-delete-the-filter-called-my-filter).

In short, deleting a filter redirects the browser to the page to immediately create a new filter, therefore you can never get rid of filters.

#### Fix

Override what the deletion button does. Clicking it would now handle the deletion correctly by hitting the link to delete a filter *without* following the redirection.

### Installation

[Direct install (GitHub)](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/se_userscript-fix-network-filter-deletion/raw/main/src/se-network-filters-deletion-fixed.user.js)

[See the code on GitHub](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/se_userscript-fix-network-filter-deletion)

(For instructions how to install userscripts: [see the tag wiki here](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info))

Code:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Stack Exchange - fix filter deletion
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @description     Deleting a filter redirects to the new filter page, thus you never get rid of filters
// @author          VLAZ
// @version         1.0.0
//
// @match           https://stackexchange.com/filters/*
//
// @grant           none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    main();

    function main() {
        //handle coming in with a delete ID set
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        if (searchParams.has("delete")) //delete and exit
            return deleteFilter(createDeleteLinkFromFilterId(searchParams.get("delete")));

        const deleteButton = document.querySelector("#yes");

        //nothing to delete
        if (!deleteButton)
            return;

        const deleteLink = deleteButton.href;

        //set the ID to delete to allow opening in new tab/window
        deleteButton.href = createActionURL(deleteLink);

        //if directly clicked, just perform the deletion immediately
        deleteButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            deleteFilter(deleteLink);
        });
    }

    function deleteFilter(deleteLink) {
        const firstFilter = document.querySelector("#sideBar .filters ul:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-child(1) .filter-name a");

        fetch(deleteLink, { redirect: "manual" })
            .then(() => location.href = firstFilter.href);
    }

    function createDeleteLinkFromFilterId(filterId) {
        return `https://stackexchange.com/filters/delete/${filterId}`;
    }

    function extractFilterIdFromDeleteLink(deleteLink) {
        const url = new URL(deleteLink);
        const pathSegments = url.pathname.split("/");
        return pathSegments[pathSegments.length - 1];
    }

    function createActionURL(deleteLink) {
        const actionURL = new URL(location.href);
        actionURL.searchParams.set("delete", extractFilterIdFromDeleteLink(deleteLink));
        return actionURL.toString();
    }
})();
```